# CS0103 in vstudio debug mode says things don't exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, using-statement

**In Debug Mode, with `using static XXX.YYY;` in place:**

My c# code works fine. But when stepping through my code in debug mode I noticed several places where the debugger says "CS0103 The name NAME does not exist within the current scope," where NAME can be a constant or a class (those are ones that I've noticed).

Both types of name references are brought into my code with a `using static XXX.YYY;` declaration, and are declared in the YYY class. Outside of debug mode, vstudio never complains, and the builds succeed without error. The code runs fine as well.

**In Debug Mode, with `using XXX;` in place:**

When I change 1) the using statement to the non-static `using XXX` format, and 2) change all code references to `YYY.name`, the debugger does not flag the names with CS0103.

Does the debugger set up some kind of special environment that messes with the 'using static' statement? Should I avoid using the `using static XXX.YYY` form and just stick with `using XXX` and `YYY.name` references?

Comment: What version of C# is your project targeting? Have you noticed anything in common with the names flagged with CS0103--for example, are they static vs not static? When you say the the debugger "flags" with CS0103, where/when exactly do you see this?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your interest. I target NET 4.7.2. The YYY items have nothing in common that I can see (other than `using static XXX.YYY`). One YYY was a simple public constant = 1, the other YYY was a static class with a dozen or two static methods doing LINQ operations. The debugger displays the message to the right of the code in the normal way like when it shows the values of local variables as you step through the code.

Comment: What is the version of C# you're targeting (not the framework version)? Also, did you say that static methods are flagged with CS0103 and also that non-static constants are also flagged with CS0103?

Comment: I don't think I target any C# version explicitly - just the default for VS 2019. Maybe 7.3 or 7.4? I'm not sure. I know it's not C# 8.0 because I wanted to use that but couldn't without a lot of hassle. One YYY was a constant: ` public const int FAILS = 1;` in a non-static class (it should have been a static class). Another YYY was a static method in a static class. Switching the `using static` statements to `using XXX` as described above made the debug mode messages go away. My code continued to work fine in both cases.

Comment: Right-click your project in Solution explorer, view the Build Advanced settings, and confirm that the Language version shows that you are using C# 7.x. I ask because I recall some issues in earlier C# versions when using static first was introduced (back, I believe, in C# 6.0). I just want to rule that out. Also, it's not so much "targeting" C# as it is specifying which C# version will be used when compiling your source code.

Comment: Under advanced settings it says (grayed out) "Automatically selected based on framework version." A documentation link says "Why can't I select a different C# version?" and the MS doc says why. The web page doc table says I'm running C# 7.3. I was thinking about your questions last night and realized that the `public const YYY` was `InstanceClassXXX.YYY` and the other `ClassYYY` was actually `InstanceClassAAA.StaticClassXXX.StaticClassYYY`. Thus, at the top level, both cases involved an instance class at or above my `using static XXX` statements. Does that help any?